# How to work with pagination URL from Soundcloud API with Retrofit

Tags: android, pagination, soundcloud, retrofit

I'm Using Retrofit to get a List of Tracks from the Soundcloud-API.
The Request results in a Callback with a List of Tracks - without Pagination this works. 
But when I add the Parameter for Pagination (linked_partitioning=1) to the Request, Retrofit returns an Error. I cannot figure out how to write the Callback-type to get URL-String to the next Page AND my List result.

Retrofit Call:

```
Map<String, String> queryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
queryMap.put("client_id" , My_Config.CLIENT_ID);
queryMap.put("tag", "loop" );
queryMap.put("license", "cc-by-sa" ); 
queryMap.put("limit", "10"); 

// This is causing  a different Return Type ---> ERROR
queryMap.put("linked_partitioning", "1" ); 

scService = RetrofitRestAdapter.getService();
scService.searchTracks(queryMap, callback); // callback function success  is not reached because of the ERROR
```

Interface for GET-Request:

```
@GET("/tracks")
public void searchTracks(@QueryMap Map<String, String> filters, Callback<List<My_Track>> cb);
```

Retrofit Callback:

```
Callback<List<My_Track>> callbackTracks = new Callback<List<My_Track>>() {
    @Override
    public void success(List<My_Track> tracks, Response response) {...}
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {...}
};
```

Retrofit Exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

**EDIT:**
Result pattern of the Soundcloud API:

Without pagination result is an Array/List of Track-Elements and looks like this:

```
[{"download_url":null,"key_signature":"","user_favorite":false,...},
{...},{...}]
```

With pagination result is an element containing a collection plus a next_href:

```
{"collection":[
{"download_url":null,"key_signature":"",...},
{...},
{...}
],"next_href":"https://..."}
```

---

How do I need to declare the returntype of Callback to separate the Collection-Array and the "next_href" from the **Result** ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you provided, I can guess,  after you requested the pagination, API returns result in an object not an array. For example, before using pagination, the result would be like

```
[
   {
      item 1,
      item 2
   },
   {
      item 1,
      item 2
   }

]
```

And after using pagination, the result would be like

```
{
   page: 1,
   count: 400,
   results: [
       {
          item 1,
          item 2
       }, 
       {
          item 1,
          item 2
       }
   ]
}
```

So you may need to change the mapping for pagination. (Since you are not providing the result pattern, this is what I think the cause of your error)

**Answer to Edit**

Currently you are mapping the returning JSON into list of My_Track class. Now you need to make another class for mapping and you declare list of My_Track as a property. Example:

```
public class MyTrackHolder {
    public final String next_href;
    public final List<My_Track> collection;

    public MyTrackHolder(final String next_href, final List<My_Track> collection)
    {
        this.next_href = next_href;
        this.collection = collection;
    }

}
```

and your interface will be like

```
@GET("/tracks")
public void searchTracks(@QueryMap Map<String, String> filters, Callback<MyTrackHolder> cb);
```

and finally call this interface method as follows

```
Callback<MyTrackHolder> callbackTracks = new Callback<MyTrackHolder>() {
    @Override
    public void success(MyTrackHolder trackHolder, Response response) {...}
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {...}
};
```

You could retrieve tracks using

```
List<My_Track> tracks = trackHolder.collection;
```

Comment: Result pattern is: {"collection":[{track1},{track2},{track3}],"next_href":"https://..."} please see edit!